# Can't get Dryad to move into house in mushroom biome for 3ds

Tags: terraria

I've built a house in a mushroom biome that I want my Dryad to move into from a different house, so that I can buy mushroom grass seeds. The banner appears in the mushroom biome house, but she won't go there.

How can I get her to move in?

Comment: what happens when you try? the fact that it's in a mushroom biome has no importance, do you already have a dryad and it won't change rooms or are you trying to get the dryad? You have to defeat one of the 4 main pre hard mode bosses to get the dryad to spawn

Comment: Okay, so I got her to move in(She changed houses) But, she won't spawn in her new house. The banner is in there. But she won't spawn in there

Comment: at night go away and then come back. During the day they just go wherever, only at night do they go to their rooms

Comment: This is not a duplicate as per OP's follow up comments, they have the NPC in a different house and want to make them move to a different house, not make them spawn

Comment: @Aequitas Please edit the question to include the comments.

Comment: @ardaozkal In the future - editing it yourself to include the information is also a valid option. :)

Answer (score 4):

NPCs usually move through paranormal means when the player isn't looking.

Go away for a few minutes and let the issue solve itself. If you've gotten far enough for long enough, your dryad is bound to have moved to her new place.